# how can i view this file in plain text in order to parse the data?

Tags: php, xml, api, parsing

http://ufc-data-api.ufc.com/api/v1/us/fighters/title_holders

I am trying to parse the data from the link above and I wanted to view the information displayed in plain text before beginning as I feel this could make it easier to read? I am not sure on how to do this, I have done things like this before but from quite a while ago so I am trying to refresh myself.

Any help would be appreciated.

My code so far is:

```
<?php

    //Calling URL XML
    $urltitleholders = ("http://ufc-data-api.ufc.com/api/v1/us/fighters/title_holders");

    //Loading URL as XML
    $titleholders_array = simplexml_load_file($urltitleholders);

    foreach ($titleholders_array as $ufcth) {

    echo "<pre>";
    echo $ufcth;
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

Comment: this is json ... and parsing json is much easier.. what do you want to get from that file.

Comment: may I ask, the api response is json, how do you are parsing it using xml_* library?

Comment: To see the _JSON_ (as others have pointed out) in plain text, simply browse to the url. I'm also guessing that you haven't checked the error log or have display errors on, since this should throw some warnings.

Comment: @MASIDDIQUI Sorry I know I am probably making silly mistakes when looking at this I just got very confused as I am trying to refresh myself. I was hoping to get - 'wins', 'losses', 'last_name', weight_class', and 'first_name' from the data

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Could you possibly provide some sample code on how to do this? I am not sure if I have parsed JSON directly before as I have only tried this a few times, thanks.

Comment: @Ryan : `$homepage = file_get_contents('http://ufc-data-api.ufc.com/api/v1/us/fighters/title_holders'); echo $homepage;` -> json -> parse it ?

Comment: `$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://.....'), true);`. That will give you the data as an array. Read more about [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) and [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) in the manual.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$url = "http://ufc-data-api.ufc.com/api/v1/us/fighters/title_holders";
$data = file_get_contents($url);
$users_data = json_decode($data, true);
$error = json_last_error();
$data_to_get = ["wins", "losses", "first_name", "last_name", "weight_class"];
if (!$error) {
    $table = "<table><tr> <th>Name</th> <th>Wins</th> <th>Losses</th> <th>Weight Class</th> </tr>";
    foreach ($users_data as $user_data) {
        $table .= "<tr><td>" . $user_data['first_name'] . " " . $user_data['last_name'] . "</td><td>" . $user_data['wins'] . "</td><td> " . $user_data['losses'] . "</td><td> " . $user_data['weight_class'] . "</td></tr>";
    }
    $table . "</table>";
    echo $table;
} else {
    echo "Error occured : $error";
}
```

Here is how you get data from json , converted to array to get specific things you need.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Sorry for that carelessness

Comment: I want to output this data into a table, I have created the table headers as below:
'<table>
<caption>UFC Title Holders</caption>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Wins</th>
<th>Losses</th>
<th>Weight Class</th>
</tr>";'

Would this be the correct code to use for example? -
echo ("
        <tr>
            <td> " .$users_data->wins. "</td>
and so on...

Comment: @Ryan it just how you get you can modify it to suite your need

Comment: Sorry to keep going on about this I just want to make sure I get this right so that I am not making any silly mistakes, would it be possible for you to show how this could be output into a table format? Even 1 example to show how this is done and I can figure the rest afterwards? Thanks I really appreciate this time and help you are providing me with.

Comment: Thanks so much you have been great help!